# Filtering out an array made out of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a simple python script to check my stats in a game and I've set the classes as an array of strings.

I now want to search within each string in the array for a specific word and if it has the word I want to set the string as a different variable.

This is what I have got so far:

```
    for k in values:
        if PVPKDRatio in k:
            UKD = k
        if PVPWLRatio in k:
            Uwinr = k
        if PVPKills in k:
            Ukills = k
        if PVPMatchesWon in k:
            Uwins = k
```

values being the array and ive set the strings as variables

```
    PVPKDRatio = "PVPKDRatio"
    PVPWLRatio = "PVPWLRatio"
    PVPKills = "PVPKills"
    PVPMatchesWon = "PVPMatchesWon"
```

and values are exactly (110 lines)

```
[<div class="trn-defstat__value">
54
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value">
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value">
<img src="https://trackercdn.com/rainbow6-ubi/assets/images/badge-fuze.9e7e92226e.png" style="height: 35px; padding-right: 8px;" title="FUZE"/>
<img src="https://trackercdn.com/rainbow6-ubi/assets/images/badge-blackbeard.fccd7e2c03.png" style="height: 35px; padding-right: 8px;" title="BLACKBEARD"/>
<img src="https://trackercdn.com/rainbow6-ubi/assets/images/badge-doc.29fe751bea.png" style="height: 35px; padding-right: 8px;" title="DOC"/>
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="PVPMatchesWon">
 115
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="PVPWLRatio">
48.5%
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="PVPKills">
784
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="PVPKDRatio">
0.93
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value">2438</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value">12/4/2020</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value">5h 6m 44s</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value">10</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value">50.0%</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value">70</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value">0.99</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="PVPAccuracy">
40.94%
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="PVPKDRatio">
0.93
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="PVPDeaths">
841
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="PVPHeadshots">
321
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="PVPMatchesWon">
115
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="PVPMatchesLost">
121
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="PVPWLRatio">
48.5%
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="PVPTimePlayed">
53h
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="PVPMatchesPlayed">
237
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="PVPTotalXp">
1,712,426
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="PVPMeleeKills">
10
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="PVPBlindKills">
0
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="RankedTimePlayed">
0h 33s
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="RankedWins">
0
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="RankedLosses">
0
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="RankedMatches">
0
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="RankedDeaths">
0
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="RankedKills">
0
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="RankedWLRatio">
0%
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="RankedKDRatio">
0.00
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="RankedKillsPerMatch">
0.00
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="RankedKillsPerMinute">
0.00
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="UnRankedTimePlayed">
6h 3m 34s
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="UnRankedWins">
10
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="UnRankedlLosses">
16
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="UnRankedMatches">
27
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="UnRankedDeaths">
195
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="UnRankedKills">
185
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="UnRankedWLRatio">
37%
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="UnRankedKDRatio">
0.95
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="UnRankedKillsPerMatch">
6.85
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="UnRankedKillsPerMinute">
0.51
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="CasualTimePlayed">
47h 44m 6s
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="CasualWins">
105
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="CasualLosses">
105
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="CasualMatches">
210
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="CasualDeaths">
646
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="CasualKills">
599
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="CasualWLRatio">
50%
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="CasualKDRatio">
0.93
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="CasualKillsPerMatch">
2.85
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="CasualKillsPerMinute">
0.21
</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value">1.06</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value">3.04</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value">70</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value">66</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value">39.13</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value">9</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value">9</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value">5</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value">SILVER III</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value">-</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value">2,318</div>, <div class="trn-defstat__value">0</div>]
```

Comment: Okay, so what is your *question*? What happened *when you tried* the code you have so far? Or if there is some other part of the problem you don't understand how to do, *what part is that*? What do you imagine are the steps to solve the problem, and what part do you need help with?

Comment: Sorry, when i run the code it says that UKD hasnt been set to anything

Comment: If each of those lines is a string within an array, then you can't just say in k, you'll have loop through and check each string I think